# Modularize React Code: Same format, different function

Tags: reactjs, components, edit

I made a simple ToDo List in React.

I have a component for Adding a new ToDo item (eg. name, title, date, place, description), and another component for Editing a ToDo item.

The 2 components however, are exactly the same, except that the Edit component is filled with content.

Is there I way I can simplify this, eg. nest a "general form" component for both the Edit and Add Component? And should I be looking into higher order components?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `renderedTodo` component and pass property `isEditing`, for example. And inside render function pick proper component to render

```
class TodoItem extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const renderedTodo = this.props.isEditing ? (<EditingTodo>) : (<AddingTodo>);
        return (
            <div>
                <div>[Common structure]</div>
                { renderedTodo }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

`TodoItem` also manages all common logic, `EditingTodo` and `AddingTodo` only logic related to them. They should be pure functions without any state and do everything using received props from `TodoItem`.